# prolem in getting particular value from json string

Tags: php, jquery, json

i want first element of json. but with data.first i am getting nothing.although alert(data) print full json string please help me out of this

```
<?php 
include_once '../con_db.php';
$rf = $_POST['rf'];
$rid = $_POST['tid'];
$data = array("first" => "one","seconed"=> "two");
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

jquery code for the ajax request is below

```
$('.fbased').focusin(function(){
   var rf = $(this).attr('id');
   var tid = $("#test_id").val();
   $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'functions/ftable.php',
    data: 'rf='+rf+'&tid='+tid,
    datatype: "json",       
    success : function(data){
        $("#"+rf).val(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You have to use `data.first` or `data.second`.

Comment: dataType with a big "T". I think its case sensitive. and then simply $('#'+rf).val(data.first);

Comment: i tried but didnt work

Comment: yes it worked for me @Ole Haugset.there should be dataType

Answer (score 0):

```
success : function(data){
    var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
    $("#"+rf).val(parsed.first);
}
```

Comment: You're more likely to have an answer accepted if you explain how your answer fits the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
$('.fbased').focusin(function(){
   var rf = $(this).attr('id');
   var tid = $("#test_id").val();
   $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'functions/ftable.php',
    data: 'rf='+rf+'&tid='+tid,
    datatype: "json",       
    success : function(data){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $("#"+rf).val(obj[0]);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.fbased').focusin(function(){
   var rf = $(this).attr('id');
   var tid = $("#test_id").val();
   $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'functions/ftable.php',
    data: 'rf='+rf+'&tid='+tid,
    datatype: "json",       
    success : function(data){
        $("#"+rf).val(data.first); // here data.first represents the specific element of json
    }
  });
});
```